# VC++ 2008, OpenProcess always returning error 5 (Access Denied)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, openprocess

Would anyone know why MSVC++ 2008 always returns error 5 on GetLastError() when I try to call OpenProcess with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS as my desired access? PROCESS_VM_READ works just fine. I'm an administrator on this computer and it is working fine in Dev C++.

Do I need to set an option somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

Opening a process with full access rights can be a highly privileged operation if it's not a process running under you credentials or in your logon session - you'll need to follow this bit of documentation from MSDN:

> To open a handle to another process
>   and obtain full access rights, you
>   must enable the SeDebugPrivilege
>   privilege. For more information, see
>   Changing Privileges in a Token.

Remember that even if you have a privilege, in most cases the privilege is not enabled - it has to be specifically enabled in the code that's attempting to use the privilege.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing that might be causing this is new to Vista:

> Windows Vista introduces protected
>   processes to enhance support for
>   Digital Rights Management. The system
>   restricts access to protected
>   processes and the threads of protected
>   processes.
>
> The following standard access rights
>   are not allowed from a process to a
>   protected process:
>
> `DELETE`
>    `READ_CONTROL`
>    `WRITE_DAC`
>    `WRITE_OWNER`

Answer (score 0):

Which process is it?  Opening a service or a process in another user session is likely to return Access Denied (5). A process in another session will open for read but you wouldn't be able to debug it.  It's one reason why Windbg has the non-intrusive attach.  It works across user sessions. You're not actually debugging.  It suspends all the threads and is reading the memory.