# how to get process handle from process id?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-vista

I have process Id , I want to get its process handle.

Is there any API available for that.

I tried to use OpenProcess but it returns NULL, and GetLastError =0.

This I am trying on Vista.

I guess I need to enable SeDebugPrivilege before using  OpenProcess .
But for enabling SeDebugPrivilege I need to get its Process handle.

Comment: Can you describe why you need this?

Comment: I've added debug privilege code for ya

Answer (score 28):

```
OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, procId);
```

You'll need to verify that you're using a valid process ID, and that you're permitted the access rights you request from the process.

Comment: Don't ask for PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, you're unlikely to get that on a secured install.  Only ask for what you need.

Comment: Right, try asking for SYNCHRONIZE, which will almost never fail.  Then step up the requested permission from there.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: how can i do this in KMDF using DDK ??

Answer (score 15):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);
CloseHandle(processHandle);
```

Also, here is some code I use to set debug privledge before injecting DLLs.

```
void Loader::EnableDebugPriv(void)
{
    HANDLE              hToken;
    LUID                SeDebugNameValue;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES    TokenPrivileges;

    if(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        if(LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &SeDebugNameValue))
        {
            TokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount              = 1;
            TokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid          = SeDebugNameValue;
            TokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes    = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            if(AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &TokenPrivileges, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL))
            {
                CloseHandle(hToken);
            }
            else
            {
                CloseHandle(hToken);
                throw std::exception("Couldn't adjust token privileges!");              
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            throw std::exception("Couldn't look up privilege value!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::exception("Couldn't open process token!");
    }
}
```

I've used the above code on Windows Vista with success.

Comment: This will return Window Handle , not Process Handle
I am looking for Process Handle from Process ID

Answer (score 1):

You would need elevated privileges. Also look at similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169355/vc-2008-openprocess-always-returning-error-5-access-denied).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same issue as described: OpenProcess() == NULL and GetLastError() == 0.
Turned out to be the Common Language RunTime Support setting, was set to "Pure" should have been just "Common". Took me ages to find.

For VS2010 c++ goto -> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a process identifier, you can get the process handle by calling the **OpenProcess** function. **OpenProcess** enables you to specify the handle's access rights and whether it can be inherited.

FYI:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684868(v=vs.85).aspx