# Determining if current process runs in WOW64 or not in Go

Tags: windows, dll, go, 32bit-64bit, wow64

With Windows, the official way of guessing if the current 32-bit process is running on a 32 or 64-bit architecture (so on WOW64 or not) is to call the [IsWow64Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from kernel32.dll, and see if it is present (as I understand the doc).

In Go we can call functions exported in dll files with the [syscall](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package, so here is my attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    dll, err := syscall.LoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer dll.Release()
    proc, err := dll.FindProc("IsWow64Process")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Proc not found") // not a WOW64 so a 32 bit system?
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", proc)

    var handle uintptr = uintptr(os.Getpid())

    var result uintptr
    v, x, y := proc.Call(handle, result)

    fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", v, x, y)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", result)
}
```

Unfortunately, testing with or without a WOW64 system displays the same in stdout:

```
&{0x10ada110 IsWow64Process 2088961457}
0 7 The handle is invalid.
0
```

What do I do wrong? How to achieve a test to determine if our 32-bit Go program runs on an emulated 32-bit on a 64-bit CPU (WOW64) or on a real 32-bit Windows?

Comment: Are you fully aware of the fact your code basically tests whether your Go code runs on WOW64 emulation or not, and not whether the OS is 32-bit arch or not? To answer the question *as stated,* you should call [`kernel32!GetNativeSystemInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340) and inspect the architecture it returns. The value will be the same no matter whether you're running 32-bit Go process on a 32-bit os or 64-bit Go process on 64-bit OS or 32-bit Go process on 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and clarification @kostix. Indeed you are right, I was biased by the fact I assumed it was a 32-bit compiled Go executable. Should I edit my question to reflect that I wanted to guess if we run on WOW64 or not and then re-ask a new question with the GetNativeSystemInfo function in Go? [It looks like it is the stackoverflow-way to handle this kind of situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283408/2583075).

Comment: Question edited to reflect what was finally asked and answered, following @kostix comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is the handle parameter on your `proc.Call`.  The expected parameter for `IsWow64Process` is a HANDLE which is not the same as a `pid`.  Which is why it is indicating that the handle is invalid.

The following SO question [How to get process handle from process id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221103/how-to-get-process-handle-from-process-id) indicates that you need to call `OpenProcess` passsing in the pid and it returns the handle.

EDIT:  GetCurrentProcess is defined in [syscall](https://golang.org/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go?h=GetCurrentProcess#L646).   So I think you can replace the `Getpid` call with the following:

```
handle, err := syscall.GetCurrentProcess()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/q6YOUS58pf) is my code so far. Unfortunately I have a runtime exception ([link](http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?11f1a1d75a631c63#xEoHdDHc6K56GtJOzlOAUrJ7qYpC6DjJI+Vv1DN94eg=)) while running it that I can't diagnose. It occurs at the proc.Call() line. Looks like it does not like affecting the `result` var?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so here is a working code:

```
package main

import (
    "syscall"
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)
func main() {
    dll, err := syscall.LoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't load kernel32")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer dll.Release()
    proc, err := dll.FindProc("IsWow64Process")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Proc not found")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",proc)

    handle, err := syscall.GetCurrentProcess()  
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Handle not found")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",handle)

    var result bool

    v, x, y := proc.Call(uintptr(handle), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&result)))

    fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n",v,x,y)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",result)
}
```

The `result` var will be true for a WOW64 system and false for a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `golang.org/x/sys/windows`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    handle := windows.CurrentProcess()
    var isWow64 bool
    err := windows.IsWow64Process(handle, &isWow64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(isWow64)
}
```