# kernel mode version of OpenProcess

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver

Is there a kernel mode version of OpenProcess function?

Basically I want to get a process HANDLE from process ID.
Specifically, I want to get the HANDLE of System Process ID.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you looking for [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221103/how-to-get-process-handle-from-process-id)

Comment: Thank you for that but correct if I'm wrong but I think that won't work in developing windows driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in an arbitrary system thread you can use ZwCurrentProcess(), otherwise you will need to figure out the ID of a system thread somehow and use ZwOpenProcess.

You might also look to see if there is a way to convert the result of PsInitialSystemProcess to a  process handle (or maybe PsInitialSystemProcess is what you are really after).

Comment: Thank you! PsInitialSystemProcess is what I needed.